Generic method to convert List<CustomObject> to Chunk<CustomObject>
I need a java method to convert Generic List of objects to Chunk.
e.g. from List<CustomObject> to Chunk<CustomObject>
The changes i have done below :
Change-1: (Working)
public static Chunk<CustomObject> convertListToChunk(List<CustomObject> listObject) {
    
    
    Chunk<CustomObject> chunkObject =  new Chunk<>(listObject);
    return chunkObject;
}

Change-2: (Not working)
public static Chunk<? extends Object> convertListToChunk(List<? extends Object> listObject) {
    
    
    Chunk<? extends Chunkable > chunkObject =  new Chunk<>(listObject);
    return chunkObject;
}

In this case we can also use BaseCustomObject like  Chunk<? extends BaseCustomObject>
where BaseCustomObject is super class of all custom object
Calling converter Method
List<CustomObjectX> finalList = new ArrayList<>();
Chunk<CustomObjectX> chk = convertListToChunk(finalList)

here CustomObjectX is any type custom object, or extends BaseCustomObject

Is this a question containing an answer? If so, then you should post the answer as an actual answer (and remove it from the question). Otherwise I am not clear about what specific question you are asking, which remains unsolved.

@andrewJames this is not a answer. the first line is the question.
and someone already answered this.

Chunk<?> is short for Chunk<? extends Object> - hence, writing that out is meaningless.
You're looking for:
public static <W> Chunk<W> convertListToChunk(List<W> list) {
  return new Chunk<W>(list);
}

Which seems useless. This method already exists. It's... new Chunk<>(list);.
Generics serves to link things. Here, you want to link the the list's component type to the chunk's type. Declare a variable (<W> declares it), then use it in at least 2 places (because generic variables used only once are either useless, or some hackery; either way not a good idea generally).
